# Bootstrap 4 Responsive Center Logo Between Navbar Links

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

i need boostrap 4 navbar with 4 links and centered logo. 2 links on left side and 2 links on right side responsive

```css
/*------------- navigation -------------*/
.site-logo {
 width: 100px;
 padding: 5px;
}

.navbar .flex-1 {
    flex: 1;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
nav#main-header {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 9999;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
nav ul {
 z-index: 10;
 height: 48px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/99adv.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark main-nav" style="background-color: #4F78F1" id="main-header">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav m-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="logo">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <img src="https://seeklogo.com/images/T/twitter-icon-circle-blue-logo-94339974C6-seeklogo.com.png" class="site-logo" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">More</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id urna quis libero egestas varius. Pellentesque et felis at est ornare mollis quis nec enim. Nulla non lorem ut metus tincidunt congue. Nullam scelerisque dolor sed viverra dictum. Integer vitae neque viverra, vestibulum ex in, vestibulum tellus. Duis quis sem dui. Nunc metus tellus, hendrerit vel tincidunt a, consectetur vitae neque. Maecenas ac eleifend lectus. Vivamus elit erat, consectetur nec tincidunt vel, dignissim in ligula. Aenean nulla justo, bibendum in lorem tristique, porta pellentesque ligula. Nulla id hendrerit turpis. Phasellus nec metus vehicula, porttitor eros id, facilisis nibh. Donec aliquam dapibus diam, eget varius ex volutpat non. Integer facilisis commodo mauris at cursus. Pellentesque eu lectus quis est sagittis tincidunt. 
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id urna quis libero egestas varius. Pellentesque et felis at est ornare mollis quis nec enim. Nulla non lorem ut metus tincidunt congue. Nullam scelerisque dolor sed viverra dictum. Integer vitae neque viverra, vestibulum ex in, vestibulum tellus. Duis quis sem dui. Nunc metus tellus, hendrerit vel tincidunt a, consectetur vitae neque. Maecenas ac eleifend lectus. Vivamus elit erat, consectetur nec tincidunt vel, dignissim in ligula. Aenean nulla justo, bibendum in lorem tristique, porta pellentesque ligula. Nulla id hendrerit turpis. Phasellus nec metus vehicula, porttitor eros id, facilisis nibh. Donec aliquam dapibus diam, eget varius ex volutpat non. Integer facilisis commodo mauris at cursus. Pellentesque eu lectus quis est sagittis tincidunt. 
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id urna quis libero egestas varius. Pellentesque et felis at est ornare mollis quis nec enim. Nulla non lorem ut metus tincidunt congue. Nullam scelerisque dolor sed viverra dictum. Integer vitae neque viverra, vestibulum ex in, vestibulum tellus. Duis quis sem dui. Nunc metus tellus, hendrerit vel tincidunt a, consectetur vitae neque. Maecenas ac eleifend lectus. Vivamus elit erat, consectetur nec tincidunt vel, dignissim in ligula. Aenean nulla justo, bibendum in lorem tristique, porta pellentesque ligula. Nulla id hendrerit turpis. Phasellus nec metus vehicula, porttitor eros id, facilisis nibh. Donec aliquam dapibus diam, eget varius ex volutpat non. Integer facilisis commodo mauris at cursus. Pellentesque eu lectus quis est sagittis tincidunt. 
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id urna quis libero egestas varius. Pellentesque et felis at est ornare mollis quis nec enim. Nulla non lorem ut metus tincidunt congue. Nullam scelerisque dolor sed viverra dictum. Integer vitae neque viverra, vestibulum ex in, vestibulum tellus. Duis quis sem dui. Nunc metus tellus, hendrerit vel tincidunt a, consectetur vitae neque. Maecenas ac eleifend lectus. Vivamus elit erat, consectetur nec tincidunt vel, dignissim in ligula. Aenean nulla justo, bibendum in lorem tristique, porta pellentesque ligula. Nulla id hendrerit turpis. Phasellus nec metus vehicula, porttitor eros id, facilisis nibh. Donec aliquam dapibus diam, eget varius ex volutpat non. Integer facilisis commodo mauris at cursus. Pellentesque eu lectus quis est sagittis tincidunt. 
</p>   
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
</html>
```

i need like bellow images

desktop view
[image]

mobile view
[image]

mobile expended menu
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far and please give some code examples of your efforts so we can help improve.

Comment: i have done some code its working fine in desktop but logo not showing in mobile view. https://codepen.io/pen/JQJwKg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use media query in your css it will works

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
```

```css
#nav-logo{
    display:block;
  }
  
  .nav-item.logo{
    display:none;
  }



@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #nav-logo{
    display:none;
  }
  .nav-item.logo{
    display:block;
  }
}

/*------------- navigation -------------*/
.site-logo {
 width: 90px;
 padding: 5px;
}

.navbar .flex-1 {
    flex: 1;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
nav#main-header {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 9999;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}

/*nav ul {
 z-index: 10;
 height: 48px;
 position: relative;
}*/
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/99adv.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark main-nav" style="background-color: #4F78F1" id="main-header">

    <div class="container">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="navbarbrand" style="margin:0 auto; position:absolute; left:42%;top:3%;"> <img src="https://seeklogo.com/images/T/twitter-icon-circle-blue-logo-94339974C6-seeklogo.com.png" class="site-logo" id="nav-logo" alt=""></a>
     <a class="navbar-brand"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler pull-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav m-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item logo" style="width:100px;">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="position:absolute;"> <img src="https://seeklogo.com/images/T/twitter-icon-circle-blue-logo-94339974C6-seeklogo.com.png" class="site-logo" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">More</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id urna quis libero egestas varius. Pellentesque et felis at est ornare mollis quis nec enim. Nulla non lorem ut metus tincidunt congue. Nullam scelerisque dolor sed viverra dictum. Integer vitae neque viverra, vestibulum ex in, vestibulum tellus. Duis quis sem dui. Nunc metus tellus, hendrerit vel tincidunt a, consectetur vitae neque. Maecenas ac eleifend lectus. Vivamus elit erat, consectetur nec tincidunt vel, dignissim in ligula. Aenean nulla justo, bibendum in lorem tristique, porta pellentesque ligula. Nulla id hendrerit turpis. Phasellus nec metus vehicula, porttitor eros id, facilisis nibh. Donec aliquam dapibus diam, eget varius ex volutpat non. Integer facilisis commodo mauris at cursus. Pellentesque eu lectus quis est sagittis tincidunt. 
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id urna quis libero egestas varius. Pellentesque et felis at est ornare mollis quis nec enim. Nulla non lorem ut metus tincidunt congue. Nullam scelerisque dolor sed viverra dictum. Integer vitae neque viverra, vestibulum ex in, vestibulum tellus. Duis quis sem dui. Nunc metus tellus, hendrerit vel tincidunt a, consectetur vitae neque. Maecenas ac eleifend lectus. Vivamus elit erat, consectetur nec tincidunt vel, dignissim in ligula. Aenean nulla justo, bibendum in lorem tristique, porta pellentesque ligula. Nulla id hendrerit turpis. Phasellus nec metus vehicula, porttitor eros id, facilisis nibh. Donec aliquam dapibus diam, eget varius ex volutpat non. Integer facilisis commodo mauris at cursus. Pellentesque eu lectus quis est sagittis tincidunt. 
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id urna quis libero egestas varius. Pellentesque et felis at est ornare mollis quis nec enim. Nulla non lorem ut metus tincidunt congue. Nullam scelerisque dolor sed viverra dictum. Integer vitae neque viverra, vestibulum ex in, vestibulum tellus. Duis quis sem dui. Nunc metus tellus, hendrerit vel tincidunt a, consectetur vitae neque. Maecenas ac eleifend lectus. Vivamus elit erat, consectetur nec tincidunt vel, dignissim in ligula. Aenean nulla justo, bibendum in lorem tristique, porta pellentesque ligula. Nulla id hendrerit turpis. Phasellus nec metus vehicula, porttitor eros id, facilisis nibh. Donec aliquam dapibus diam, eget varius ex volutpat non. Integer facilisis commodo mauris at cursus. Pellentesque eu lectus quis est sagittis tincidunt. 
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id urna quis libero egestas varius. Pellentesque et felis at est ornare mollis quis nec enim. Nulla non lorem ut metus tincidunt congue. Nullam scelerisque dolor sed viverra dictum. Integer vitae neque viverra, vestibulum ex in, vestibulum tellus. Duis quis sem dui. Nunc metus tellus, hendrerit vel tincidunt a, consectetur vitae neque. Maecenas ac eleifend lectus. Vivamus elit erat, consectetur nec tincidunt vel, dignissim in ligula. Aenean nulla justo, bibendum in lorem tristique, porta pellentesque ligula. Nulla id hendrerit turpis. Phasellus nec metus vehicula, porttitor eros id, facilisis nibh. Donec aliquam dapibus diam, eget varius ex volutpat non. Integer facilisis commodo mauris at cursus. Pellentesque eu lectus quis est sagittis tincidunt. 
</p>   
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: i need logo in centered on both views mobile and desktop and also half logo on navbar and half outside navbar.. like in my 1st question. check the screen shots.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. but the logo is not in center and also navbar height is too much .. i need logo in absolute position half on navbar and half bellow navbar..

Comment: @Arman check the updated answer. I added position absolute for logo as per requirement